# Azure Data Factory: Dataset Dynamic DB Table name not resolving in Data Wrangling Flow

Tags: azure-data-factory, dataflow, data-wrangling

I created a DataSet which points to a table in my database. The name of the table is set as dynamic content: `@concat(dataset().db_prefix, '_Baseline_CIs')`. This works when checking in the ﻿Dataset through 'Preview Data'. The table contents are shown.

BUT: When using the dataset in the Data Warngling Flow, the M-query fails with the following error:

```
Expression.Error: The key didn't match any rows in the table.
AdfDoc = Sql.Database("oedudigital.database.windows.net", "IntegratedEnvironments"),
  InputTable = AdfDoc{[Schema = "dbo", Item = "undefined"]}[Data]
```

As you can see, the table name concatenation has returned 'undefined'. Is this a bug?

BR, Denis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it right you have the DataSet which is parameter , at least that was the case on my side . Under the AdFResouce you will see the dataset name . You will have to pass the table name as

AdfDoc{[Schema = "dbo", Item = "**TableName**"]}[Data]
and then it will bring in the records .

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this a workaround. But I will need to file a feature request for resolution of parameters during design time.